# OneNote - Not able to find all the Property IDs in the Microsoft documentation

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I am parsing One Note documents.

When I find property IDs from within the OneNote documents, I find most of them in the OpenSpecs document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-one/e9bf7da8-7aab-4668-be5e-e0c421175e3c?redirectedfrom=MSDN

But there are quite a few that seem to appear in OneNote files that I do not see in the Spec:

```
 0x14001c9e
 0x14001c9f
 0x14001ca0
 0x14001ca1
 0x14001df9
 0x1400348b
 0x1c001d61
 0x1c001df8
 0x1c001dfb
 0x1c001dfc
 0x1c001e30
 0x1c0035b7
 0x88001c8e
 0x88001cbd
 0x88001cdc
 0x88001d13
 0x88003462
```

Where do I find information about these properties?